# left: initial doesn't work in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In IE, the tooltip is not shown like I want.

That's the correct display (chrome):

[image]

That's the wrong display (IE)

[image]

And that's my css:

```
.tooltipfullscreen:hover:after {
    left: initial;
    right: 0;
    transform: none;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

IE doesn't support the `initial` keyword, and support for it was only just added to Microsoft Edge.

There really isn't much of a point using `initial` with properties like `left` — it's pretty well-known that the initial value of those properties is `auto` so just hardcode that in.

Comment: Like how you did with `transform: none` instead of `transform: initial`.